# Iterating via nested loops

Tags: ansible

The `packages.yml` file defined as:

```
---
- packages:
    - name: Some description 1,
      packageList:
        - package1,
        - package2,
        - package3

    - name: Some description 2,
      package: package4
```

The first item contains a field `packageList`, the 2nd item does not have it, but only `package` field.

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - packages.yml
```

How to iterate via all `packageList` items of the `packages` list only if this `packageList` is defined for an item.

Here is how I can iterate through items which contain `package` field:

```
- name: iteration
  debug:
    msg: "name: {{ item.package }}"
  when: item.package is defined
  with_items: "{{ packages }}"
```

Comment: Judging by the name of the file, are you by any chance trying to install multiple packages (as in yum/apt packages)? If so, it will be much more efficient to simply pass the list to the `apt`/`yum`/`package` module - see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html ( "it is much more efficient to pass the list directly to the name option.")

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my comment, if you simply want to install multiple yum/apt packages, it is usually more efficient to simply pass the list to the `apt/yum/package` module. As [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html) state:

"When used with a loop: each package will be processed individually, it is much more efficient to pass the list directly to the name option."

However, if you really need a loop, here is a possible solution:

playbook.yml:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - packages.yml

  tasks:
  - name: iteration over single items
    debug:
      msg: "name: {{ item.package }}"
    when: item.package is defined
    with_items: "{{ packages }}"

  - name: iteration over lists
    debug:
      msg: "name: {{ item.packageList }}"
    when: item.packageList is defined
    with_items: "{{ packages }}"

  - name: Do something with individual packages in the list
    include_tasks: process_list.yml
    vars: 
      mylist: "{{outer.packageList}}"
    when: outer.packageList is defined
    loop: "{{ packages }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: outer
```

process_list.yml:

```
- name: See what we have received
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{mylist}}"
```

result:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [iteration over single items] *******************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={u'packageList': [u'package1,', u'package2,', u'package3'], u'name': u'Some description 1,'}) 
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'name': u'Some description 2,', u'package': u'package4'}) => {
    "msg": "name: package4"
}

TASK [iteration over lists] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'packageList': [u'package1,', u'package2,', u'package3'], u'name': u'Some description 1,'}) => {
    "msg": "name: [u'package1,', u'package2,', u'package3']"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={u'name': u'Some description 2,', u'package': u'package4'}) 

TASK [Do something with individual packages in the list] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={u'name': u'Some description 2,', u'package': u'package4'}) 
included: /root/tmp/process_list.yml for localhost

TASK [See what we have received] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=package1,) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "item": "package1,"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=package2,) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "item": "package2,"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=package3) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "item": "package3"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The loop_control/loop_var part is used because otherwise both the outer and inner loop will use {{item}} as the loop variable - and this will cause... interesting results :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a default value with an empty list for the cases, where the `packageList` is undefined.

```
{{ item.packageList | default ([]) }}
```

If the `packageList` is undefined, the job iterates over an empty list, which means, it does not do anything.

Comment: but I iterate over one list - inside another. `packageList` is a nested list. How to iterate throught it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `default`, as @ceving mentioned:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars_files:
  - packages.yml

  tasks:
  - name: iteration
    debug:
      msg: "name: {{ item.packageList | default([item.package]) }}"
    with_items: "{{ packages }}"
```

If `packageList` exists, it will use that, else `package` put into a single-element array to match the form of `packageList`:

```
PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [iteration] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "name: [u'package1,', u'package2,', u'package3']"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "name: [u'package4']"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```